# Comparing Time Values with Odd Format

Tags: excel

I have a list of games played durations and the frequency of those durations. See the list below for my example data set.

```
Duration    Frequency
0:01 min    1
0:04 min    1
0:08 min    2
0:09 min    1
0:10 min    1
0:11 min    3
0:12 min    2
12:03 min   1
19:40 min   1
2:28 min    1
25:54 min   1
3:58 min    1
34:57 min   1
4:23 min    1
4:25 min    1
45:16 min   1
5:13 min    1
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't sort my duration from lowest to highest. I would like to sort my duration so that I can make my charts show the frequencies based on duration. As of now my charts show frequency without considering the duration.

My cell format for these values are "General" and I can't appropriately assort them. Can you please help me out? I've tried replacing the ":" with a "." and that doesn't help. I've also used a new field to remove "min" and leave the remaining values but again that doesn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're going to need to write some VBA code to convert the intervals to seconds (extract the full minutes left of the `:`, convert to an integer, and multiply that integer by 60) and then add the seconds to the right of the `:` (again converted to an integer). The result goes into a new column, which you can then use to sort the data.

Answer (score 1):

with data in columns **A** and **B**, in **C2** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(TRIM("00:" & LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2))))
```

and copy downward.

[image]

Then sort the three columns by column **C**